# "Ser primero" vs "ser el primero"

Tags: gramática, artículos

¿En esta película de Hollywood traducida al español https://youtu.be/aGxyZsiB9Mg por qué en 52:28 un hombre dijo "*ser primero*" y en 52:43 dijo "*ser **el** primero*" en vez de "*ser primero*"? ¿Eso pasó porque la palabra "primero" fue mencionada otra vez? Pero pensaba que eso pasa solamente en el caso de los artículos indefinidos y definidos:

"*Hoy compró **un** coche azul. **La** coche la va a manejar hoy*".

¿También puede pasar lo mismo en plural? Es decir, ¿que "ser primeros" se convierte en "ser los primeros"?

Comment: [el coche, not la coche.] El coche, lo va a manejar hoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu frase de ejemplo no está bien:

"Hoy compró un coche azul. Ella va a manejar el coche hoy." ("La coche la va a manejar hoy" no tiene sentido)

En tu ejemplo no hay un "el coche" porque se haya mencionado antes, simplemente porque debe haber un artículo antes del sustantivo, es incorrecto decir "va a manejar coche hoy".

Respecto a "ser primero" versus "ser el primero" tienen en esencia el mismo significado en el vídeo que señalas. Podría haber repetido dos veces "ser primero" o "ser el primero".